# Facebook php api conflict between url and picture

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Something strange happens using the facebook feed, if I enter the destination URL in the format "app.facebook.com/..." the stream of public information correctly including the attached image, but if I change the link in the "www.facebook.com/page_name/APP_ID", no image appears into stream.

Code below:

```
$publishStream = $facebook->api("/$session/feed", 'post', array(
            'message' => "Message",
            'picture' => URL_APP,
            'name'    => 'Name',
            'description'=> 'Description',
            'link' => 'https://www.facebook.com/PageName?sk=app_1447229...',
       )
);
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no error. The post will appear without image